# How to get sum of column from specific representatives orders?

Tags: sql-server, sum

I have a column called balance and another column called repnum. Repnum represents a representative who's taken care of customers. I've managed to grab the customers name, the specific representative i'm looking for (15), and I know I can grab the balance by taking out (sum(balance)) but what I want to do is get the sum of the balance column with only representative 15's orders. This is what I currently have thought up:

```
select customername, repnum, sum(balance) balance from customer where repnum = '15'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an over clause to the sum function to prevent the need for group by:

```
Select customername, 
       Repnum,
       Sum(balance) over(partition by repnum) balance
From customer
Where repnum = 15
```

Comment: Works perfectly, could you by any chance explain what partition does? From looking at it, it seems like it's saying add everything in repnum.

Comment: [Start here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx), play with it on other window functions, you'll understand it better then I can explain.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just add `group by customername, repnum` to the end of your query.

Comment: If you want to sum balance for each customer and repnum, yes.